# trouble trying to render partial with jquery ajax and rails format.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial

I want my rails 3.x controller to render a partial instead of the full view when called by ajax.  I've seen examples like

```
def show
    @rec = Rec.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.js { render partial: @rec } # for ajax response
    end
end
```

But for rails to respond with the partial I've got to append .js to my url or set dataType: 'script' in my ajax call.  I've tried

```
$.get("/recs/1.js")
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#right_pane').html(data);
    })
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/recs/1", 
    dataType: "script"
}).done(function(response) {
    $('#feed_right').html(response);
})
```

However if I do either of these things I get parserror or syntaxerror from jquery, understandably so because I'm returning HTML not javascript.

Thoughts on how to do this neatly, without resorting to a js.erb?

Answer (score 0):

I appended .js to the url then set the dataType to html, like so.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/recs/1.js", 
    dataType: "html"
}).done(function(response) {
    $('#feed_right').html(response);
})
```

Makes sense I suppose.